# Swiffy not showing in Android webview

Tags: android, flash, webview, google-swiffy

I have an swf file I want to play on android, but since swf is not officially supported on android 4.0+, I'm using google swiffy to convert swf to html5.
I have tried this code but it is not working, webview just showing white blank screen.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);  
        WebView wv;  
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/swiffy.html");
    }  
}
```

Swiffy code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/481mlqc8ym497q1/swiffy.html?dl=0

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? We are not psychic. Better explain differences between what you expect & what you actually see on Android. Did it ever work on desktop browser at least? Can you put **swiffy.html** online so we test?

Comment: webview just showing white blank screen, this is my swiffy.html file https://www.dropbox.com/s/481mlqc8ym497q1/swiffy.html?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Untested at the moment but... I'm wondering if there's a security issue with your HTML (on local storage) trying to access an online file? If **swiffy.html** was online it might work normally, but since it's on storage then make sure the JS file is on same place in storage too.

The source of **swiffy.html** loads a `https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.4/runtime.js`

**Possible fix :** 
1) Save this **[JS file](https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.4/runtime.js)** to the same place as your **swiffy.html**

2) Edit the source code of **swiffy.html**, change the line below...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.4/runtime.js"></script>
```

To become like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/runtime.js"></script>
```

Save as **swiffy_v2.html** and test that in your webView code as :

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/swiffy_v2.html");
```

**Edit from comments :**
Another fix is to just add the allowing of internet access in the app's manifest file. This solves the issue of loading the online JS file from a local HTML file.

Comment: thanks man, it's works when i save the JS file into same storage and modified swiffy file into like this..

`<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/runtime.js"></script>`

and if you dont want to save the JS file to storage, just add internet permission into manifest file its works also..

Comment: Ahh.. forgot about `file:///android_asset/` path but at least you understood since it has to be in same place as HTML. Glad it's all working for you now.